# Spring cloud aws set endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-aws

I user Spring cloud AWS  for connecte to my Amazon S3  in openStack
by default the endpoint is s3.amasonaws.com I want change the endpoint because my bucket S3 us in the private cloud not in public amazon cloud.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

.
.
.
.

```
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

....
in my application.properties

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.region.static=eu-west-3
storage.s3.accessKey=AKIAJNGI4VX4DTY4U24Q
```

thinks for your help.

Comment: dos'nt existe property  cloud.aws.endpoint ???

Comment: no, it does not

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem trying to use LocalStack with S3 configured locally in my machine. As Spring Boot doesn't have an option to configure the endpoint, we had to define the bean by ourselves. Then, we just had to use the newly defined bean.

```
/**
 * It must be configured, if we need to upload a file using the LocakStack configuration.
 * Because of it, we must define a new client since the default one has not an option to configure the Endpoint.
 *
 * @see org.springframework.cloud.aws.context.config.annotation.ContextResourceLoaderConfiguration.Registrar#registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry)
 */
@Bean(name = "amazonS3Client")
public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider,
                               RegionProvider regionProvider,
                               @Value("${aws.s3.default-endpoint:https://s3.amazonaws.com}") String endpoint) {

    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpoint, regionProvider.getRegion().getName()))
        .build();
}
```

Comment: how do you tell spring to use this bean instead of the autoconfigured client?

Comment: You can use @Primary annotation.

Comment: You can `@Autowired AmazonS3 amazonS3Client`

Comment: @LeQuangNhan Amazon default S3 client does not have the option to configure the endpoint to use with Localstack.

Comment: @FelipeDesiderati yep, I know. my comment is for "how do you tell spring to use this bean instead of the autoconfigured client?"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cloud.aws.s3.endpoint` property to override the endpoint.

Comment: There is no `cloud.aws.s3.endpoint` property in version 2.2.6.RELEASE. Not sure what version you used.

Comment: Well, the documentation says `cloud.aws.s3.endpoint` which "Overrides the default endpoint". https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html

Comment: but the `.endpoint` is actually not work, even for `cloud.aws.sqs.endpoint`, test on spring version 2.7.2.